# Get URL + Title from HTML parsed from JSON

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get the URL and Title from JSON output, which contains HTML.
Basicaly it renders a couple of ads which i need in an app, and that is why i need the URL, Image and the link to it, but i am not sure how to get it into an object in an easy way and show them randomly to the user.

Content below

```
[
{
    "content": {
      "rendered": "&lt;div class=\"g g-20\"&gt;&lt;div class=\"g-dyn a-144 c-1\"&gt;&lt;a href=\"https://www.knalverhuur.nl/\"; class=”gofollow” target=\"_blank\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"https://www.oldambtnu.nl/wp-content/banners/knal-verhuur.png\"; width=\"393\" height=\"100\" srcset=\"https://www.oldambtnu.nl/wp-content/banners/knal-verhuur.png 393w\" sizes=\"1281px\" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"g-dyn a-155 c-2\"&gt;&lt;a class=\"gofollow\" data-track=\"MTU1LDIwLDEsNjA=\" href=\"http://www.westers-kozijn.nl/\"; target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"https://www.oldambtnu.nl/wp-content/banners/westers-kunstof-kozijnen-fabriek.png\"; width=\"290\" height=\"100\" srcset=\"https://www.oldambtnu.nl/wp-content/banners/westers-kunstof-kozijnen-fabriek.png 290w\" sizes=\"1281px\" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"g-dyn a-137 c-3\"&gt;&lt;a href=\"https://zekerheidzonderzorgen.nl/\"; target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"https://www.oldambtnu.nl/wp-content/banners/hpmobiel-1.png\"; width=\"290\" height=\"100\" srcset=\"https://www.oldambtnu.nl/wp-content/banners/hpmobiel-1.png 290w\" sizes=\"1281px\" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"g-dyn a-85 c-4\"&gt;&lt;a class=\"gofollow\" data-track=\"ODUsMjAsMSw2MA==\" href=\"http://www.motorshop-fransen.nl/\"; target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"https://www.oldambtnu.nl/wp-content/banners/banner-motorshop-fransen-2.png\"; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"g-dyn a-138 c-5\"&gt;&lt;a href=\"https://www.meubelspuiterijscheper.nl/nl/\"; target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"https://www.oldambtnu.nl/wp-content/banners/meubelspuiterij-scheper.png\"; width=\"290\" height=\"100\" srcset=\"https://www.oldambtnu.nl/wp-content/banners/meubelspuiterij-scheper.png 290w\" sizes=\"1281px\" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;\n",
      "protected": false
    },
]
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good thing to un-escape HTML entities first. You can do it with following method:

```
function htmlDecode(input) {
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
    return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}
```

I am not sure what you mean by title, but URL can be extracted via following regex:

```
var patt = /href="(.*?)"/g;
while(match = patt.exec(str)){
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```